# Segmentation fault in Rails application with a table of millions of data rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, segmentation-fault

I am working on a rails app where I populated a table with 4 million data rows. When I try to show the page in my view in shows no data ! From the server log I can see the error :

```
/Users/Rakib/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@rails328/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:607: [BUG] Segmentation fault
```

It shows the following message at the end:

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

I tried the same table with less amount of data and then it worked perfectly. Is this because of huge amount of data in a single table? How can I solve this problem? Any kind of help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to show all 4 million at once?

Comment: yes, because I need to get all the data rows from this page to use somewhere else !

Comment: I think it might be time for you to learn some SQL, trying to work with 4e6 rows at once outside the database is just a complicated way to have a bad time. What exactly are you trying to do that makes you think you need to work with an array of four million ActiveRecord objects?

Comment: You are right, I will use sql command to get the required data from the table. Actually, in this big table there are data about 15,000 stocks. I will have to import these data to another website, for 1 stock there will be 1 table. So, I think, I can run sql commands to get the data for a particular stock and will show them to that another website. This is possible right? One question, how can I get data rows using sql in a ruby program? Using sequel gem? or any other easier option? Thanks for you reply.

Comment: You can use `select_rows` on `connection`: `connection.select_rows(%q{...}).each { |row| ... }`. Push as much of the query logic down into the database as you can (despite the absurd Rails dogma about never putting any logic in the database) and review your indexes and EXPLAIN output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely running out of memory.

Rather than loading all the millions of rows at once, load them in chunks and copy them to their destination, discard the chunk, load the next chunk, and repeat.

You can do this using a PostgreSQL [cursor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html) and [the `FETCH` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-fetch.html). Some client libraries can use protocol-level cursors when iterating over result sets; I don't know if Ruby's `Pg` gem can.

If you're using ActiveRecord, reconsider. It's not a sane way to manage millions of rows in bulk transactions. If possible do it with lower level SQL operations.

Comment: Yeah, I will use sql to get the data. Thanks for your nice idea, +1 :-)